# Newtonsoft JSON Deserialization not working as expected

Tags: c#, json.net

Given this JSON

```
{
  "docType": "payment-remittance-v1.4",
  "fields": {
    "Customer Name": {
      "type": "string",
      "valueString": "xxx",
      "spans": [
        {
          "offset": 284,
          "length": 43
        }
      ]
    },
    "Payment Reference": {
      "type": "string",
      "valueString": "3875014846",
      "content": "3875014846",
      "confidence": 0.92,
      "spans": [
        {
          "offset": 167,
          "length": 10
        }
      ]
    },
    "Remittance Date": {
      "type": "date",
      "content": "16.02.2023",
      "confidence": 0.97,
      "spans": [
        {
          "offset": 180,
          "length": 10
        }
      ]
    },
  },
  "confidence": 0.125,
  "spans": [
    {
      "offset": 0,
      "length": 1048
    }
  ]
}
```

And these classes

```
public class PredictionFields
{
    [JsonProperty("Customer Name", Required = Required.Always)]
    public BaseField CustomerName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Payment Reference", Required = Required.Always)]
    public BaseField PaymentReference { get; set; }
}
public class BaseField
{
    [JsonProperty("confidence")]
    public double Confidence { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("valueNumber")]
    public double ValueNumber { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("valueString")]
    public string ValueString { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

}
public class Document
{
    [JsonProperty("docType")]
    public string DocType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public PredictionFields Fields { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("confidence")]
    public double Confidence { get; set; }
}
```

I get an error `Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Required property 'Customer Name' not found in JSON. Path 'fields', line 82, position 3.`

I'm perplexed as to this because the property is defintely listed in the JSON.

I have created a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VYrnWW) - be glad of any help, have been puzzling this for hours!

Comment: Maybe you can try adding the PropertyName parameter to the JsonProperty attribute.
`[JsonProperty("Customer Name", Required = Required.Always, PropertyName = "Customer Name")]`

Comment: @Raynoceros That works! What's the default string() constructor for JsonPropertyAttribute then if its not PropertyName?

Comment: If you deserialize JSON with the default constructor of JsonPropertyAttribute, it will look for property names that match the member names in the class. The default constructor for JsonPropertyAttribute sets the property name to the name of the member being serialized or deserialized.

Comment: it is typo ... you are using different spaces ... [working fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z1IPYQ)

Comment: @BrendanGooden Your classes are mess (and a json too)  and because of this you have lost a half of data. But JsonProperty("Customer Name",  Required = Required.Always) is correct and I don't know why did you get that error.

Comment: Apparently its a dumb question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the Property Name to PredictionFields should solve the problem:

```
public class PredictionFields
{
    [JsonProperty("Customer Name", Required = Required.Always, PropertyName = "Customer Name")]
    public BaseField CustomerName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Payment Reference", Required = Required.Always, PropertyName = "Payment Reference")]
    public BaseField PaymentReference { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: [Million Monkeys Programming Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_permutation)